# hide custom tabbar when push

Tags: ios

I have a customized tabbar in my app. I want to hide my tabbar when pushing another viewcontroller. 
Currently I implemented as this(The original tabbar has been hidden):

```
myViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
((CustomTabBarController *)self.tabBarController).customTabBar.hidden = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:lookBookViewController animated:YES];
```

But when it is being pushed, it hides my customTabBar immediately. So you can see a black bottom bar in  first viewcontroller. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

put your these code in `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated;`

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    myViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    ((CustomTabBarController *)self.tabBarController).customTabBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

you can design like this
[image]

and then you need not to hide the tabbar , if you want to hide it , you can use my above code , I think if you design like this , the hide effect will be you want

Comment: Only add last sentence in viewDidDisappear method, the customTabBar disappeared after myViewController presented. Still not as perfect as native tabbar, which only show tabbar in previous viewcontroller.

Comment: @yibuyiqu it is the problem with your design , you can see my update